# semidirect product and isomorphic maps

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $H, N$ be subgroup swith $N$ normal. Let $\gamma_x$ be conjugation by an element $x \in G$. I nkow that $x \mapsto \gamma_x$ induces a homomorphism $f: H \rightarrow Aut(N)$. I want to show: if $H\cap N = \{e\}$, show that the map $H\times N \rightarrow HN$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is a bijection, and that this map is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ is trivial, i.e. $f(x) = id_N$ for all $x \in H$.

This is what I have thus far: If $H\cap N = \{e\}$, show that the map $H\times N \rightarrow HN$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is a bijection, and that this map is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ is trivial, i.e. $f(x) = id_N$ for all $x \in H$.

I'm having some trouble with the converse.

Comment: You mean $H \cap N = \{e\}$ instead of $H\cup N = \{e\}$?